# How to specify API key in Google Cloud Datalab map Google Chart?

Tags: google-visualization, google-cloud-datalab

Enjoying getting to know Google Charts and Cloud Datalab. Came across this example that requires an API key and can't determine how to communicate it to the library:

```
%%sql --module taxi

DEFINE QUERY locations
  SELECT FLOAT(pickup_latitude) AS lat, FLOAT(pickup_longitude) AS lon, medallion
  FROM [833682135931:nyctaxi.trip_data]

DEFINE QUERY geohashes
  SELECT lat, lon,
         CONCAT(STRING(FLOOR(lat*1000+0.5)/1000), ':', STRING(FLOOR(lon*1000+0.5)/1000)) AS geoid,
         medallion
  FROM $locations
  WHERE lat != 0 AND lon != 0

DEFINE QUERY hotspots
  SELECT FIRST(lat) AS lat, FIRST(lon) AS lon, COUNT(medallion) AS pickups
  FROM $geohashes
  WHERE ABS(HASH(medallion)) % 1000 == 1
  GROUP BY geoid
  ORDER BY pickups DESC
  LIMIT 25
```

New cell:

```
%%chart map --fields lat,lon,pickups --data taxi.hotspots
showTip: true
mapType: normal
key: {my-key-here}  # <- just my guess at how to specify the key
```

Needless to say this didn't work. Originally it threw an error, but now it completes and leaves a blank white space where the chart should be.

How should they be specified in the Google Cloud Datalab cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key needs to be specified in the notebook's Javascript global namespace. Run this in a cell before running your map cell:

```
%%html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```